# Extracting integers from strings without sstream c++

Tags: c++

What is the simplest way to extract the following integers from a string such as: "54 232 65 12".

And what if the last number is a long long int. Is it possible to do this without sstream

Comment: Apply `strtoul` repeatedly and use the end pointer it gives you.

Comment: Use `sprintf` instead of `sstream`

Comment: Note that the proper `C++` way is sstream.

Comment: Do *not* use `atoi`.  It can't report errors, and can't handle your `long long` either.

Comment: Using c++11 you can do with stoi

Comment: @sgar91 -- `sprintf` is to write to a string; ITYM `sscanf`.

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use `sstream`?

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cerrno>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    char str[] = " 2 365  2344 1234444444444444444444567 43";

    for (char * e = str; *e != '\0'; )
    {
        errno = 0;
        char const * s = e;
        unsigned long int n = strtoul(s, &e, 0);

        if (errno)                       // conversion error (e.g. overflow)
        {
            std::printf("Error (%s) encountered converting:%.*s.\n",
                        std::strerror(errno), e - s, s);
            continue;
        }

        if (e == s) { ++e; continue; }   // skip inconvertible chars

        s = e;

        printf("We read: %lu\n", n);
    }
}
```

In C++11 you can also use `std::strtoull`, which returns an `unsigned long long int`.

([Live example](http://ideone.com/OjHuPP).)